# When is $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq \int_a^b f(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $$g(x)\leq1,\forall x\in[a,b]$$

then is it always true that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq \int_a^b f(x)dx$ for any $f$ and $g$?

In general, if $$g(x)\leq h(x),\forall x\in[a,b]$$

then is it always true that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \leq \int_a^b h(x)f(x)dx$ for any $f,g$ and $h$?

Comment: Assuming $f(x)\geq 0$, then $m(x) = f(x)g(x) \leq f(x)$. What can you say about $\int_{a}^{b}m(x)\ dx$?

Comment: @JoshuaWang, so this only works for $f\geq 0$?

Comment: @gbd well, you can put more sophisticated conditions but yes $f\geq 0$ is a reasonable condition. Take $f(x)=-1$ for all $x$, what can you say about your inequalities?

Comment: @Surb, the inequality reverses...?

Answer (score 2):

Another answer points out some exceptions to your hypothesis. However, it is true for nonnegative functions. The key property of the integral at play here is called *monotonicity*, which means that if $f_1(x) \leq f_2(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, then
$$ \int_a^b f_1(x) \text{ d}x \leq \int_a^b f_2(x) \text{ d}x.$$
In this case, we have $f(x)g(x)$ and $f(x)h(x)$ in the roles of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, respectively. But you need the nonnegativity assumption to ensure that they satisfy the inequality you want!

The proof of monotonicity of the integral is fairly simple: show that the Riemann sums which approximate the integral are monotone, then invoke the Order Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily (suppose $a<b$). For example take $f = -1$ on $[a,b]$ and $g=0$ on $[a,b]$. Then
$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) = 0
$
But $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) = -(b-a) < 0$.
You need more restrictions on $f$, por example if you restrict $f$ to be non neggative then the result is true, and it follows from the inequality $f(x)g(x) \leq f(x)$ .